# Need help filtering documents with criteria inside array - mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Need help with query to filter the records in mongoDB. I am using compass to run the que
We have thousands of records/documents where each record/document contains the following array. For few documents, the events in `lifeCycleinfo` are out of order i.e. `payment.completed` event comes before 1payment.completed1 event.

I need to filter those records where `completed` event comes before `created` event

```
{
  "lifeCycleInfo": [
    {
      "eventId": "9b8b6adfae",
      "eventSubType": "SendTransfer_Receipt",
      "eventType": "SendTransfer",
      "odsTimestamp": {
        "$date": "2023-02-06T14:33:42.308Z"
      },
      "payload": "{}",
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2023-02-06T14:33:42.271Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventId": "06e8d144-531b02",
      "eventSubType": "payment.created",
      "eventType": "Notification",
      "odsTimestamp": {
        "$date": "2023-02-06T14:33:45.488Z"
      },
      "payload": "{}",
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2023-02-06T14:33:45.479Z"
      }
    },
    {
      "eventId": "9da54454d6",
      "eventSubType": "payment.completed",
      "eventType": "Notification",
      "odsTimestamp": {
        "$date": "2023-02-06T14:33:46.698Z"
      },
      "payload": "{}",
      "timestamp": {
        "$date": "2023-02-06T14:33:46.689Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to find it based on array index but not working.

```
{"lifeCycleInfo[1].eventtype":"payment.completed"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$reduce` with `$switch` to iterate through the `lifeCycleInfo` array and keep track of the status with an object `{inOrder: <bool>, seenCreated: <bool>}`. We can conditionally set the 2 bools and use the final result to get the matched documents.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      inOrderResult: {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$lifeCycleInfo",
          "initialValue": {
            inOrder: false,
            seenCreated: false
          },
          "in": {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.eventSubType",
                      "payment.created"
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    inOrder: "$$value.inOrder",
                    seenCreated: true
                  }
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.eventSubType",
                          "payment.completed"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$value.seenCreated",
                          true
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": {
                    inOrder: true,
                    seenCreated: true
                  }
                }
              ],
              default: "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "inOrderResult.inOrder": true
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dll0bN8oRp2)